# Sencha Touch/Cordova app devastated after Android Level 18 Jellybean 4.3 Update in HTC One

Tags: html, sencha-touch-2, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I am reaching out because I feel like we can't be the only ones who are experiencing this problem, however right now based on my research I feel quite alone!

Last night I got the android update (4.3) on my HTC One which I installed right away.  Now the app we developed with Sencha Touch + Cordova hardly functions at all.  This is after a successful submission to the app store and successful testing in multiple android devices.

Some of the issues we are experiencing:

1. Back button in list view no longer responds
2. Page transitions (left->right and right<-left) functioning bizarrely.  For example the title transitions right to left while the body left to right, simultaneously.
3. The title on our home screen suddenly reverting to "undefined."

I know probably all we need to do is get back to the emulator and just start debugging, but we really would like to know whether anyone else has experienced problems like this and could help point us in the right direction on some solutions.

Also the problems persist after updating to the very latest version of Sencha Touch 2.3 which has Cordova integrated.

Comment: Video demonstrating one of these issues: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pPspFnLDYvY

Comment: Also experiencing similar issues on HTC One running 4.3 (touches within list views not responding). This is the only handset that this problem had been reported for, and 4.2.x seems fine. Anyone have any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following patch resolves the issue!

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?273492-Back-button-broke-in-navigationview-Sencha-Touch-2.3-Android-4.3&p=1009111&viewfull=1#post1009111

Looking forward to seeing this implemented in the next Sencha Touch update.